# Inline-block form elements wrap when padding is applied and whitespace exists between

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My problem is that for the div classes `form-profile` and `form-profile-side`, if I want 2 of those divs, they must be on the same line within the HTML:

```
<div class="span13">
  <form class="form-profile-side"></form><form class="form-profile"></form>
</div>
```

if I put the second class on a new line, it messes up the layout (this is what I'm trying to do):

```
<div class="span13">
  <form class="form-profile-side"></form>
  <form class="form-profile"></form>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.form-profile-side {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-right: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 0x 0px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}

.form-profile {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 817px;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
```

**How do I make it so that I can create a new line in the HTML using the class, instead of having it all on one line?**

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VzTxM/4/

Comment: what do you want to do? what is your goal? be more specific ...

Comment: How do I make it so that I can create a new line in the HTML using the class, instead of having it all on one line?

Comment: Please provide a link to your site or some example working code that we can manipulate. Possibly consider using jsFiddle or a similar site.

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/VzTxM/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/VzTxM/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue you're having (if i understand the question right) is that the display:inline-block; is adding a lil spacer when the HTML is on two seperate lines - you can fix this by flaoting the elements instead?

**CSS**

```
.form-profile-side,.form-profile {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
    background-color: #fff;
    float:left;
}
.form-profile-side {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 0x 0px 0px 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-right: 0;
  width: 120px;
}
.form-profile {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px;
  width: 817px;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="span13">
  <form class="form-profile-side"><br><br></form>
  <form class="form-profile"><br><br></form>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```